# Not sure how to tackle this

Tags: python

So I have this assignment:

[image]

I'm not quiet sure how to start to tackle this. I know that it is pretty much a step-by-step on what to do, but it is a little confusing. This is supposed to be written in python. Maybe I'm making this harder than it should be? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks guys.

Comment: You're making it harder than it is.  Start by creating a class and then do exactly what it says.

Comment: See [help/on-topic], point #3: _Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it._

Comment: This assignment doesn't look like it was designed for Python. There's no such thing as a private field in Python, and the closest thing to a private field has to start with an underscore.

Comment: Go through the question and look carefully for the useful bits, like "the class contains" and "methods" and "constructor." That said, this looks like a textbook for some other language, with its talk of private variables, specific types for each variable, and accessors ("get" methods) and mutators ("set" methods). And, of course, if it was really Python, it would be faster to code it than to make the UML diagram.

Comment: Probably Java homework ._.

Comment: Thats what I figured. The terminology seems to be for java.

Comment: Did your instructor just give the class this screenshot without the rest of the book?

Comment: @Shashank - looks like it's Java homework in Python clothing (see my answer).

Answer (score 3):

I have located the book that contains this assignment.

[Introduction to Programming Using Python by Y. Daniel Liang](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132747189)

(Okay, due to only having this snippet to go on, I actually found a PDF of the book first, but that had the title of the book, so here we are.)

It does indeed call itself a Python book. In addition to the decidedly unpythonic exercise given in the OP's question, it even has a whole section (section 15.11) on tail recursion. The very first thing it says in that section, in an emphasized font face:

> A tail recursive function is efficient for reducing stack size.

I looked through the rest of the section, and it never mentions the fact that Python **does not have tail call optimization**. For an explanation of that decision, read [Guido's blog post about it](http://neopythonic.blogspot.com/2009/04/tail-recursion-elimination.html).

This book was published in 2013, so it's not like it's outdated or wrestling with an immature platform. My theory is that the author, a "Java Champion" who gives lectures on Java, simply speaks Python with a very heavy Java accent, and the result is barely comprehensible.

My recommendation to the OP is to ask the instructor to use a different textbook - like the [official Python tutorials](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/), for example.

Comment: Wow...he's a "Java champion" from 2005, and talks about tail recursion in a Python book...yet JVM and CPython both lack tail call optimization. That's just funny. :) My education was in C++ and I was taught about tail call optimization, but when I moved into languages like Java and Python for building applications, I quickly learned that the JVM and CPython don't have these features. My guess is he was educated in some C-like language, read a lecture about tail optimization, and automatically assumed that all compilers/interpreters do it without doing the research...

Answer (score 2):

I wrote the class for you:

```
class Fan(object):
    SLOW = 1
    MEDIUM = 2
    FAST = 3
    def __init__(self, speed=SLOW, on=False, radius=5.0, color="blue"):
        self._speed = speed
        self._on = on
        self._radius = radius
        self._color = color
```

Accessors and mutators are for Java people.

Comment: The kind of teacher who would assign this in Python would also take points off for not having explicit accessors and mutators for the "private" attributes.

Comment: That teacher should be fired, or worse.

Comment: I think the entire assignment was for Java people. I'd like to downvote the professor in this case.

Comment: @JoshuaGrigonis Or worse?

Comment: Forced to write something in Java.

Comment: Forced to write UML diagrams for Internet Explorer 6

Comment: @chepner - I guess it depends on whether it's a Java professor teaching a Python class (see my answer).